# Finding the sum of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to write 6 small JavaScript scripts for school and I've got them all working apart from this one.

```
function calculate() {
    var numbers = [
        document.getElementById("num_one").value ,
        document.getElementById("num_two").value ,
        document.getElementById("num_three").value 
    ];
    var sum = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2];
    document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

The user is supposed to enter 3 numbers click a button and it should add them all togther or "find the sum".

My Problem is, it just joins the numbers togther instead of adding them. Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: Because you are adding 3 string values

Comment: inputs have strings as values, you will have to parse them as numbers with either `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()`

Comment: So `var sum = +numbers[0] + +numbers[1] + +numbers[2];`

Comment: Or `var sum = 0;
numbers.forEach(function (value) {
    sum += +value || 0;
});
document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;`

Comment: _please_ use `numbers_1` etc, instead of `numbers_one` !  Better yet, use a class instead of (or in addition to) IDs so that a single selector will find all of the elements that you wish to sum

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are "summing" string variables so Javascript is concatenating them.

You need to convert them to numbers in order to have an arithmetic sum:

```
function calculate() {
        var numbers = [
            document.getElementById("num_one").value ,
            document.getElementById("num_two").value ,
            document.getElementById("num_three").value 
        ];
        var sum = Number(numbers[0]) + Number(numbers[1]) + Number(numbers[2]);
        document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Parse string using **[`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)**, **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** or **[`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)**, for converting it's to number. Otherwise `+` will just do string concatenation , since the values are string.

```
function calculate() {
  var numbers = [
    document.getElementById("num_one").value,
    document.getElementById("num_two").value,
    document.getElementById("num_three").value
  ];
  var sum = parseFloat(numbers[0]) + parseFloat(numbers[1],) + parseFloat(numbers[2]);
  document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

---

```
function calculate() {
  var numbers = [
    document.getElementById("num_one").value,
    document.getElementById("num_two").value,
    document.getElementById("num_three").value
  ];
  var sum = Number(numbers[0]) + Number(numbers[1]) + Number(numbers[2]);
  document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

---

```
function calculate() {
  var numbers = [
    document.getElementById("num_one").value,
    document.getElementById("num_two").value,
    document.getElementById("num_three").value
  ];
  var sum = parseInt(numbers[0], 10) + parseInt(numbers[1], 10) + parseInt(numbers[2], 10);
  document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `value` property is `string`. In order to use it in arithmetic operations, you need to parse it to integers. The simpliest way to do this in JS is `+x`.    You can use `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` to make it easier:

```
var ids = ['num_one', 'num_two', 'num_three'];
var sum = ids
    .map(function(x) { return +document.getElementById(x).value; })
    .reduce(function(a,b) { return a+b; }, 0);
```

With this way, you will be able to introduce new elements into calculations with minimal changes.

Comment: Why the extra call for `.map()`? The query part can be moved into the `.reduce()` call. The array is small but why iterate the array(s) twice?

Comment: @Andreas if performance isn't a concern, IMHO it's cleaner to separate the functionality of extracting the values from the subsequent addition of them

Answer (score 2):

`.value` return `String` you need convert it to `Number`,

you can do it with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`(if you have float values), or with `Number()` or just add `+` before value

```
var numbers = [
    +document.getElementById("num_one").value,
    +document.getElementById("num_two").value,
    +document.getElementById("num_three").value
];
```

or

```
var numbers = [
   Number(document.getElementById("num_one").value),
   Number(document.getElementById("num_two").value),
   Number(document.getElementById("num_three").value)
];
```

or

```
var numbers = [
   parseInt(document.getElementById("num_one").value, 10),
   parseInt(document.getElementById("num_two").value, 10),
   parseInt(document.getElementById("num_three").value, 10)
];
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest approach is to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

in combination with [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

> The `Number` JavaScript object is a wrapper object allowing you to work with numerical values. A Number object is created using the Number() constructor.
>
> The primary uses for the Number object are:
>
> - If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN.
> - In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion.

and then [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

in combination with a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Sum_all_the_values_of_an_array) like

```
function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Together in a single line with your code wrapped:

```
function calculate() {
    var numbers = [
            document.getElementById("num_one").value,
            document.getElementById("num_two").value,
            document.getElementById("num_three").value
        ],
        sum = numbers.map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; });
    document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Comment: There must be a way to use `map()` to populate the `numbers` array in the first place, too, even though the OP didn't ask for that...

Answer (score 2):

A scalable solution in one line of es6:

```
var sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);
```

Be sure to include an `initialValue` at the end there - it'll guarantee the callback is executed and a number is returned in cases where the array contains no values/one value.

[More info on reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: don't forget to include the trailing `0` argument, otherwise `reduce` will fail unless there's at least two elements in the array.

Comment: @Alnitak Seems to work with one element, although fails if empty

Comment: ah yes - I didn't quite remember the rules properly.  If there's only one element, it returns it without invoking the callback [implying that you'll still get a string in this case, not a number].  Hence you should still supply the zero to ensure that the callback is invoked to apply the conversion.

Comment: @Alnitak True, in OP's particular example returning a string to innerHTML shouldn't matter but I'll update it for general use case

Comment: also (not withstanding performance), how about `var sum = numbers.map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`

Comment: @Alnitak I originally had something similar to that but felt it would be less efficient :/

Comment: yes, it is strictly slightly less efficient, but it's not like this code is in a tight loop anywhere.  It's certainly cleaner, though, since it completely separates the type conversions from the additions.  On the flip side, `Number(a) + Number(b)` does make it clear that we are in fact doing addition and not concatenation :/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether your input numbers are integers or decimals, you can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat).

Answer (score 1):

There are already plenty of reasonable answers, but here's a neat shorthand alternative:

```
var sum = +numbers[0] + +numbers[1] + +numbers[2];
```

Comment: I see that @ArunPJohny already added this as a comment. Apologies for the duplication.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `javascript` treats `input` values as strings. So you have to manually convert them to `integers` like this:

```
var numbers = [
    document.getElementById("num_one").value ,
    document.getElementById("num_two").value ,
    document.getElementById("num_three").value 
];

document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML =
    numbers
        .reduce(function(sum, element) { return sum + parseInt(element, 10);}, 0);
```

What is good about this code, is that if you need to calculate for more than three elements you only need to modify your `numbers` array.

Comment: I wouldn't say "by default", since you can't actually change it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use an array to store the inputs like

```
<script>
var numbers;

function push(){
  numbers.push(getDocumentById("someid").val;
}


function calculate(){
  var sum=0;
  for(i=0; i<numbers.len; i++){
    sum=sum + numbers[i];
  }
    alert(sum);
}

</script>

<div>
  <button id="someid" value=20 onClick="addToArray();">click to push</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="calc" onClick="calculate();">click to calculate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will solve the problems:

```
function calculate() {
var numbers = [
    +(document.getElementById("num_one").value) ,
    +(document.getElementById("num_two").value) ,
    +(document.getElementById("num_three").value) 
];
var sum = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2];
document.getElementById("display_sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```